# Xamarin Forms add input field to each item of listview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and I would want to add a input field (Numeric) on the right side of each item in my listview, so that I can type a quanty to my items. Somthing like a shopping list of items with the quantity of how many you want.

here is my code of my listview

```
List<string> item = new List<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        item.Add("Apple");
        item.Add("Banana");
        item.Add("Graps");
        item.Add("Orange");
        item.Add("Pineapple");
        item.Add("Strawberry");
        item.Add("Lemon");
        item.Add("Mango");
        item.Add("Cherry");
        item.Add("Watermelon");
        item.Add("Add");

        var listView = new ListView
        {
            RowHeight = 40
        };

        listView.ItemsSource = item;

        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();

        layout.Children.Add(listView);



        listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Add")
            {
                var MyEntry = new Entry { Placeholder = "new item" };
                layout.Children.Add(MyEntry);
                MyEntry.Completed += MyEntry_Completed;

            }
        };

        this.Content = layout;

    }

    private void MyEntry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = ((Entry)sender).Text;
        item.Add(text);

    }
```

Comment: I invite you to read the online documentation : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/
If you want the Entry to be displayed only when user click on an item, juste hide it when you create the cells of your list and display it when you want it

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble wrapping my head around databinding from the C# side in Xamarin Forms. I would recommend you checkout [DataBinding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#Custom_Cells) to get a better understanding of this. I created a custom ViewCell for you to play around with, and a basic implementation so you can get a visual of how to implement it. You can adjust the view cell as much as needed. I just wanted to give you a bases of how to implement it. Hope this helps.

**ViewCell**

This is the view that displays for each list item in the list view.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BountyApp.Controls
{
    public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        private Grid _grid = new Grid();
        private Label _lbl = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End, VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center };
        private Entry _entry = new Entry();


        public CustomViewCell()
        {
            _lbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Title"));
            _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star) });
            _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0.7, GridUnitType.Star) });

            _grid.Children.Add(_lbl, 0, 0);
            _grid.Children.Add(_entry, 1, 0);

            View = _grid;
        }

    }
}
```

**Implementing ViewCell**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BountyApp.Pages
{
   public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
    public class StepperPage : ContentPage
    {
       public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> List { get; set; }

        public StepperPage()
        {
            List = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
            List.Add(new ViewModel { Title = "Apple"      });
            List.Add(new ViewModel { Title = "Banana"     });
            List.Add(new ViewModel { Title = "Graps"      });
            List.Add(new ViewModel { Title = "Orange"     });
            List.Add(new ViewModel { Title = "Pineapple"  });
            List.Add(new ViewModel { Title = "Strawberry" });

            var listView = new ListView
            {
                RowHeight = 40, 
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomViewCell)),
                ItemsSource  = List
            };


            Content = listView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: suppose if i am entering all the data to Entry Control and submit how would i come to know which entry data is for which label ? can u help me with that ?